# How can I make my laptop hibernate/sleep when the charger is removed?

Tags: windows, windows-10, power-supply, power-management, hibernate

My laptop doesn't have battery. I'm using it with direct power supply. So the problem is that whenever the electricity goes off or when the charger is unplugged, my laptop shuts down and my work is disturbed.

Is there any way that when the charger is removed by mistake or when electricity goes off, my laptop hibernates/sleeps automatically and I don't lose my work?

(I'm using Windows 10).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

Sleep is a state where the computer will still need a small amount of power to save its state - so when you start again, it resumes at where you left it.

Hibernate is a state where information of your laptop state is SAVED into the HDD and then it will go into hibernate state and no longer requires power until you re-start the machine. In which it will read the hibernation state, reload everything, and resumes at where you left it.

BOTH process requires TIME for the laptop/windows to prepare itself to enter either Sleep or Hibernate State. Sleep state is a lot faster compared to Hibernate, but sleep NEED power (even a tiny amount) to keep that sleep state.

If you got "accidental" power unplug - and no battery - it will go down.

If you still have your old dying battery (battery that maybe last 5-10 minutes) - THAT could be your savior. That amount of time MAYBE enough for the laptop to enter either sleep or hibernate. The idea is that you lose power (cable unplugged) - your dying battery tell windows "I only got 5%" - Windows initiate sleep / hibernate process. In the time, hopefully you have enough time to replug the cable. You will still need to let Windows complete the Sleep/Hibernate process, but at least you won't lose data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Or buy a UPS. That will give you enough time to safely shutdown.